# How to look for an item in DB when the type is String | String[] using typescript union types

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am calling a method `sendEmail` that sends an email to a single user or a bunch of users(the type of to email is `string | string[]`)

Is there a cleaner/better way to determine if it's an array or a single user so that I can look for it in the DB accordingly? The code looks quite repetitive now.

```
  public async sendEmail(
    toEmail: string | string[],
  ): Promise<void> {
    if (!Array.isArray(toEmail)) {
      const user = await this.userRepository.getUserByEmail(toEmail);
      await checkIfPaymentMade(user);
    } else {
      for (const email of toEmail) {
       const user = await this.userRepository.getUserByEmail(toEmail);
        await checkIfPaymentMade(user);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: COnsider this https://tsplay.dev/mbG02W . It is easier to read `Array.isArray` rather than `!Array.isArray`

Answer (score 1):

A few other options come to mind

1. Extract the common code to its own function. There's still some duplication, but just one line instead of however long the helper function needs to be.

```
public async sendEmail(
  toEmail: string | string[]
): Promise<void> {
  if (!Array.isArray(toEmail)) {
    await doStuff(toEmail);
  } else {
    for (const email of toEmail) {
      await doStuff(email);
    }
  }
}

private async doStuff(toEmail: string): Promise<void> {
  const user = await this.userRepository.getUserByEmail(toEmail);
  await checkIfPaymentMade(user);
}
```

2. Have the body of the function only work with standalone strings. If it's an array, recurse.

```
public async sendEmail(
  toEmail: string | string[],
): Promise<void> {
  if (Array.isArray(toEmail) {
    for (const email of toEmail) {
      await sendEmail(email)
    }
  } else {
    const user = await this.userRepository.getUserByEmail(email);
    await checkIfPaymentMade(user);
  }
}
```

3. Have the body of the function only work with arrays. If it's not an array, turn it into one first.

```
public async sendEmail(
  toEmail: string | string[],
): Promise<void> {
  const emailArray = Array.isArray(toEmail) ? toEmail : [toEmail];

  for (const email of emailArray) {
    const user = await this.userRepository.getUserByEmail(email);
    await checkIfPaymentMade(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I like second solution. It might be worth considering using `for await ... of ` loop

Comment: I just rearranged my post, so you may mean the 3rd one now (which is my preference too)

Comment: yes, it also might be a matter of the style, but I think it worth to create new variable/constant for `toEmail` to avoid argument mutation

Comment: Yeah, i can see the benefit of not reassigning the argument. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep it DRY, here's an option:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzAAtwBrASUQAUoBPAWxFQwFkpR4AKZAZxBgC54aEqhwB3VAEpBlGDjpZeAHgBuOLMAB8AbgCwAKAOQo3bvACiADyh0ADhAQBvA-CG8YAJRC2c3LBhwYGkEoVBo9Q31XW2QAIwgsMHgTGnR4XlRgczooLAhOODAsWyxGDG5BbgwYLFQAc3gAH3Tq2rqAbQBdaXhZeUUQVXUteGco1yRAzjA8KuTgYDhTeBxEeABBGBhaADpFTe2aDkLi0qZuSXgAfngTkrKzQXa7s-Lu0ZcJ1xnUOZ4+eAAXmSYlyGHgGEIih2-083l8-kCNB2dRAGAAqu4AEI0bK5CAcNiLECmSQRL6uKCg-wEYhgchUWgMJisUBcdxkz6uAC+n15+n5QA)

```ts
public async sendEmail (recipients: string | string[]): Promise<void> {
  for (const address of Array.isArray(recipients) ? recipients : [recipients]) {
    const user = await this.userRepository.getUserByEmail(address);
    await checkIfPaymentMade(user);
  }
}
```